# How to write some text in a dynamically TextBox

Tags: c#

I have to do a crossword puzzle and its textboxes are dynamically created. At some point of the game, I need to fill it up with the correct pettern (data) from database.

Here it is what I've made so far.

```
public void GenerateCrosswordAdmin()
{
    string crossWordName = cb_cw.Text; // the name of the table

    string dbPath = Application.StartupPath + @"\CrossWord.mdf";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + dbPath + ";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from CrossWords where name='" + crossWordName + "'";
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    int ROWS = 0;
    int COLS = 0;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        ROWS = Convert.ToInt32(reader[2]);
        COLS = Convert.ToInt32(reader[3]);
    }
    cmd.Dispose();
    reader.Dispose();

    MyTextBox mtb = new MyTextBox(ROWS, COLS, tabControl1); // triggers the constructor to work with cols and rows

    cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from Solves where Id='" + idCrossWord + "'";
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        mtb.col = Convert.ToInt32(reader[1]);
        mtb.row = Convert.ToInt32(reader[2]);

        string solution = reader[4].ToString();
        foreach (char c in solution)
        {
            mtb.Text = c.ToString().ToUpper();
            mtb.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            if (reader[3].ToString() == "horizontal")
            {
                mtb.col++;
            }
            else mtb.row++;
        }
    }
}

public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public TabControl tabControl1;
    public static List<List<MyTextBox>> tbs { get; set; }
    public static List<MyTextBox> tbslist { get; set; }
    public int row { get; set; }
    public int col { get; set; }
    public MyTextBox() { }
    public MyTextBox(int rows, int cols, TabControl tabControl1)
    {
        tbs = new List<List<MyTextBox>>();
        tbslist = new List<MyTextBox>();
        this.tabControl1 = tabControl1;

        Point p = new Point(20, 30);
        for (int row = 1; row <= rows; ++row)
        {
            List<MyTextBox> newRow = new List<MyTextBox>();
            tbs.Add(newRow);
            for (int col = 1; col <= cols; ++col)
            {
                MyTextBox tb = new MyTextBox();
                tb.Name = "tb_CWAdmin";
                tb.Size = new Size(25, 25);
                tb.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 8, FontStyle.Bold);
                tb.row = row;
                tb.col = col;
                tb.Location = p;
                newRow.Add(tb);
                tbslist.Add(tb);
                //tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(tb_TextChanged); // don't need it for this problem
                tabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(tb);
                p.X += 25;
            }
            p.X = 20;
            p.Y += 20;
        }
    }

    /*public void tb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
        string upLetter = tb.Text[0].ToString().ToUpper();
        tb.Text = upLetter;
        tb.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    }*/
}
```

When the application is opened, a comboBox is populated with some crossword puzzles names, stored in database. Once one is selected, the game with all correct data should apper on the screen.

My table is correctly generated, but the textboxes are not filling up with text.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyvkX.png)

Comment: Wait, your class that inherits a TextBox also has a TabControl in it?  With Lists and Lists of other MyTextBoxes?  That's...confusing.

Comment: Instead of `mtb.Text = ...` do something like `mtb.tbs[mtb.row, mtb.col].Text = ...`. But as @LarsTech says. It is confusing to put information related to other controls in `MyTextBox`. Instead create a class `CrosswordGrid` not derived from `TextBox` for those things. Or derive it from `Panel` and put the textboxes on this panel.

Comment: The TabControl was necessary because that's how my homework sounded. I've posted a picture of how it looks right now. So I need to create this grid within the tabControl1, on the first page. The lists are there because of my attempts. I didn't manage to find a solution to the problem, so I posted it. That's why the lists aren't currently used. In my mind it was a good idea to use lists of ```MyTextBox``` ...

Comment: Inheriting from a TextBox doesn't look necessary.  I would get rid of it.  Create a UserControl that houses that grid of TextBoxes, or use a Grid control instead.  That TabControl would just be a control on the form (assuming WinForms).

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean by userControl / gridControl. Could you explain me a bit of how it will look / be used?

Comment: A grid control has columns and rows.  Seems self-explainable.